# Windows application that debug battery consumption

Tags: windows, battery

Does someone knows an application for Windows that debugs battery consumption? Im looking for some  software that could estimate the remainder batteries energy under some specific conditions. I would like to know which processes are consuming more energy (based on processor and i/o uses). Actually, any tool that could give some information would be nice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know of any application, but you could create the conditions you want and run this code on the command prompt:

`powercfg -energy -output %USERPROFILE%\Desktop\PowerCFG_Analysis.html`

It will monitor your system for 60 seconds and then generate an easy to read .html file on your desktop with reported findings.

Save the report, change the conditions and retest.

[Source](http://www.coreymahan.com/how-much-is-each-process-in-windows-responsible-for-draining-my-battery/).

I just tried this out and was fairly impressed. It not only tells you about various processes but also the hardware usage.

Comment: I used powercfg and be able to know which process are consuming more battery. Thanks