# How to measure the power consumed by a program in Windows?

Tags: windows-7, windows, power, measurement

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows application that debug battery consumption](https://superuser.com/questions/318240/windows-application-that-debug-battery-consumption)

I have the following dilemma: 
I am testing several programs which have power saving features that can be used on laptops running on battery. I want to measure the effectiveness of such features and learn if they are garbage or not. In other words, I want to find a way to measure the power consumption of a program with the power savings features disabled and then with them enabled.

Is there a way to do this via software measurements, in Windows? It doesn't have to be a very exact measurement. Approximations will do just fine.

Comment: I don't believe that this is a duplicate. The suggested duplicate question asked about total consumed battery power, but this question is about current power consumption rather than what was already consumed.

Answer (score 2):

Programs are not electrical devices and do not consume power. Moreover, your typical computer
is running dozens of programs at the same time, even if it appears to the user that only
"one" application is running. What you could do is run your program for a period of time under
"typical" conditions and measure the computer power consumption with your wattmeter of choice.
Compare the results you get with the various settings you want to test.